# Parsing string in LUA

Tags: parsing, lua

I have been looking around and have read a lot of different answers but none seems to answer my specific request.

I make watchfaces for Wear OS 2 with an app called ''WATCHMAKER'' witch uses LUA as language.  I want to make a watch face with a special clock pointing to a number depending on a blood sugar value sent by an transmitter connected to the body.

The string values I want to parse follows this syntax:

```
<DECIMAL NUMBER> <ARROW> (<TIME>)
```

One example would be

```
5,6 -> (1m)
```

I want to extract the `<DECIMAL NUMBER>` part of the reading. In the above example, I want the value `5,6`.

Every 5 minutes, the transmitter sends another reading, all of those informations change:
5,8  -  (30 secondes)

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Say you have a string, in LUA, `s="14,11 -> (something)"` and you want this first number of the string to be parsed to a float so you can do maths on it.

```
s='9,6 -> (24m)'
-- Now we use so called regular expressions
-- to parse the string
new_s=string.match(s, '[0-9]+,[0-9]+')
-- news now has the number 9,6. Which is now parsed
-- however it's still a string and to be able to treat
-- it like a number, we have to do more:
-- But we have to switch the comma for a period
new_s=new_s:gsub(",",".")
-- Now s has "9.6" as string
-- now we convert it to a number
number = string.format('%.10g', tonumber(new_s))
print(number)
```

Now `number` contains the number `9.6`.